# Dice probability (allowing user to leave some dice)

Tags: probability, dice

I am trying to calculate probability in a dice rolling scenario.

Specifically, when I throw 12 dice, and I want to get at least 5 equal pairs.

That is, either:

1,1  2,2  3,3  4,4  5,5

Or

1,1      2,2  3,3  4,4  6,6

Or

1,1  2,2  3,3  5,5  6,6

…

I want to find out the P of the above, by having 2 chances.

With “by having 2 chances” I mean: you throw the dice, and you are able to leave any pairs you have… That is, if you get among the 12 dice 3,3 and 4,4 and 5,5  you **keep** those and throw again the remaining 6 dice.

(Whenever I google this, “2 chances” means that you throw all the dices in each chance, which is not what I am looking for)

Comment: The rules are not clear.  All of your numerical examples have five distinct pairs.  Is that a rule?  What if you got, e.g., $111,\,222,\,333,\,444$?  or $1111,2222,3333$?   or twelve $1's$?   Also:  What have you tried?  A usual place to start would be to consider a smaller number...like three dice, looking for at least one pair. Or  five dice looking for at least two, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. So, you have to reach at least 5 (different) equal pairs.

If you get 111, you keep 11 and throw again the remaining '1'.

If you get 1111, you keep 11 and throw again the two remaining '1'.

Comment: So, edit your post to reflect all the rules.  And to indicate what you have tried.